# use of “etc” in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Is use of "etc" in a sentences correct grammatically?

> As shown in Fig. 5, the experimental results curve (Fig. 5(a) and (c))
>   lies below the numerical points because mechanical losses such as the
>   bearing, gears and **etc** are included in experimental results while
>   these losses cannot be consider in numerical results.

The figure is as follows:

[image]

Comment: **"and etc."** is redundant, because the abbreviation **etc.** stands for the Latin _et cetera,_ which means _"and so forth."_ This means that "and etc." means, literally, _**"and and so forth",**_ which is obviously nonsensical. The author here is announcing that he or she has no idea what "etc." means!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of

> [etc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JHH6iwgIek)

is usually restricted **from** anything technical since "etc" *implies* and *assumes* and can be ambiguous which is usually not good practice in technical writing.